# How can I get rid of this black, default border that appears after div is clicked?

Tags: html, css

As in the topic, I want to get rid of this black default border that appears after this div is clicked.
As you can see, it ruins my styles:

[image]

Comment: .element {border:none;} did you try this?

Comment: but you should add some codes to specify your issue